# Why addEventListener ('wpcf7mailsent') in contact form don't work?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, yandex-metrika

Website is on **wordpress** with **contact form 7** plugin installed.

I was connected to Yandex metric, set the goal and tap `addEventListener` to forms, but I can not understand why the goals don't reach, although mails delivered..

I try to do it different ways, but couldn't find any errors in the console.
`addEventListener ( 'wpcf7mailsent')` don't work..

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
   (function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){m[i]=m[i]||function(){(m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments)};
   m[i].l=1*new Date();k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)})
   (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");

   ym(41441674, "init", {
        clickmap:true,
        trackLinks:true,
        accurateTrackBounce:true,
        webvisor:true
   });
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/41441674" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        ym(41441674, 'reachGoal', 'weddings'); return true;
console.log('weddings');
});
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener ( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    ym(41441674, 'reachGoal', 'zayavka');
console.log('zayavka');
}, false);
document.addEventListener ( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    ym(41441674, 'reachGoal', 'zayavka');
console.log('wpcf7submit');
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Note: your "console.log(...)" in the callback from the "wpcf7mailsent" event will never be reached, because your "return true;"

Comment: @Marc  10x, but if I put under `"return true;" ` - I can catch it?

Comment: Right, everything after a `return` statement is ignored